# vim: how to let vim use apostrophe as start of a string

Tags: vim

I am working on a sql file with some m4 macro embedded. Since m4 uses apostrophe to mark the start of string literals, it breaks the string highlighting of the file totally. Like

```
m4_include(`SQLCommon.m4')
```

I am wondering whether there is any option we can let vim to pair apostrophe with a single quotation mark. I searched on-line but didn't find any answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to override vim's normal syntax highlighting for `sqlString`.

I was able to get the behavior I think you're looking for with just this:

```
:syntax region m4String start=/`/ end=/'/
```

To achieve nesting, we have to tell vim that a m4 string can contain more of the same:

```
:syntax region m4String start=/`/ end=/'/ contains=m4String extend
```

If you'd like to color those strings separately instead of just disrupting the normal highlighting you can separately link to the String highlight group.

```
:hi link m4String String
```

---

I wasn't entirely sure what you were looking for though; if the backtick-apostrophe delimited strings are inside of the normal SQL strings this won't work.

Comment: it works great, and thanks! one more question, the apostrophe and quotation mark in m4 can also be nested. do you know how we should deal with it? thanks again!

Comment: I've added a syntax definition that will allow nesting. Make sure to `:syntax clear m4String` otherwise both definitions will stick around.